# Log files are not copied properly in Linux server using Jboss server

Tags: linux, jboss

Here some of the log files(Feb 6,7 and 8 are very less data, But 2,3 and 4 are having very large data) are not properly copied in Linux Jboss server.,

```
***

> -rw-rw-rw-   1 admin    ae           93 Feb  8 00:01 invoker.log.08
> -rw-rw-rw-   1 admin    ae          168 Feb  7 00:02 invoker.log.07
> -rw-rw-rw-   1 admin    ae          156 Feb  6 00:02 invoker.log.06

***
-rw-rw-rw-   1 admin    ae      122602761 Feb  4 23:59 invoker.log.04
-rw-rw-rw-   1 admin    ae      130182661 Feb  3 23:59 invoker.log.03
-rw-rw-rw-   1 admin    ae      133208599 Feb  2 23:59 invoker.log.02

and here is the log4j file.


log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG,ROL
log4j.appender.ROL=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ROL.File=*******/*****/invoker.log
log4j.appender.ROL.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.ROL.Append=true
log4j.appender.ROL.DatePattern='.'dd
log4j.appender.ROL.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ROL.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n;

Thanks and Regards,
Raju.
```

Comment: Kindly please response anybody.

Comment: Kindly response anybody regarding on this issue.

Comment: Kindly please provide some support on this and let me know any input you required .

Comment: log rotation not working for DailyRollingFileAppender